# カメラプレビューをリアルタイムで白黒変換しながら、撮影をして保存したい。

Tags: android, java, opencv

以下のことを同時に実現させたいと思っております。

1. カメラプレビューをリアルタイムで白黒変換する。
   Camera の onPreviewFrame でピクセルを操作することによってモノクロにしています。
2. 動画を撮影する。
   MediaRecorder を用いて録画しています。

1 と 2 はそれぞれ単体のテストで成功しています。MediaRecorder を使っていると Camera の onPreviewFrame は触れることができないので、実装がうまくいきません。
まずは OpenCV を用いない方針で考えていて、どうしても無理なら OpenCV を使った方法も考えています。
Android での動画撮影に詳しい方、ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

動画撮影には詳しくありませんが、AndroidJavaからどうにかするには、`onPreviewFrame`か何かで受け取ったデータを[MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)で直接変換するしか方法がなさそうです。16未満がターゲットですと、指定の条件では手出してきません。

ちなみにOpenCVではモノクロ画像に変換はできますが、それを動画として保存するにはffmpegが必要で、さらに、ffmpegを使うように`WITH_FFMPEG=YES`でOpenCVをコンパイルする必要があるようです。